# ember map object from ember data store

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am trying to map an object in the model hook. I have this object provided by mirage.

```
let temp = {"users": [
    {
        "id":1,
        "forename":"Test",
        "surname":"Name"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "forename":"Hans",
        "surname":"Solo"
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "forename":"Peter",
        "surname":"Pan"
    }
]
```

};

In the model hook I want to use this:

```
return this.get('store').findAll('user').then(x => x.map(x => x.id + x.forename + x.surname));
```

I am getting this:

> 1[object Object][object Object] 2[object Object][object
>   Object] 133000[object Object][object Object] 3[object
>   Object][object Object]

And I am using this in the template (at the moment just for test if it works):

```
{{#each model as |SingleUser|}}
{{SingleUser}}
{{/each}}
```

I tried to just map to the ID and this works fine. Furthermore it works fine if I will declare the temp directly in the model hook. Is there anything with promise which impede my map?

I need this working because I am implementing a ember power select multiselection and I want to show the user the id, forename and surename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember wrapping all POJOs in the store with Ember Object.
Unlike POJO, Ember Objects have getters/setters and you should use it like:

```
obj.get('property');
obj.set('property', 'value');
```

You should change your code to:

```
.then(x => x.map(x => x.get('id') + x.get('forename') + x.get('surname')));
```

Here are only a few words about getters and setters in official guide:
[Ember Guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/object-model/classes-and-instances/#toc_accessing-object-properties) (at the bottom of the page). You also may read get/set API (URLs to API in the guide article).

Also, take a look at [computed properties](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/object-model/computed-properties/). Probably, this is will be usable in your case.

Comment: Works! Thank you very much